# Is there a way to prevent duplicate insert into influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I am inserting a measurement with a `guid` id as one of the tag like this,

```
insert cpu,id=acaf4a7d-9f2f-49d6-b87c-1101e76dc56d,asset=a1 value=10
```

Let say with same `id`, same `asset=a1` and same `value=10` I am inserting one more time same series,

```
insert cpu,id=acaf4a7d-9f2f-49d6-b87c-1101e76dc56d,asset=a1 value=10
```

Then I have duplicate data for the measurement with only different in `time` (of course)

Question is, since I have same `id`, can we prevent duplicate insert?

[image]